# New instance of a class c#

Tags: c#

This may have been asked many times, and I've been searching around, but for some reason, this doesn't make sense to me. So it seems like I create a new instance, but Visual studio tells me that `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

```
public class Test{
   private Dictionary<string, Service> serviceList;
   private void GetList(string ID){
       foreach(var service in Service.Load()){
            servicelist.Add(service.ID, new Service());
       }
   }
}
```

I think when I use new Service(), I basically create a new instance of the Service every single time I move to the next element in the Dictionary? **Service** is a class

Comment: Yes, you do. Please consider reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa0ab757.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx.

Comment: Well, a new one gets created for each service in service.Load and is *added* to the dictionary. I'm not sure what you mean by "Move to the next element". So, what is your question exactly? Just that a new instance is created?

Comment: yeah I read that before, but not sure why I get the error that I posted above. I forgot to include it

Comment: yes you are right a new instance will be created each iteration and a reference  will stored in  dictionary

Comment: you don't initialize `serviceList`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa0ab757.aspx

Comment: so Service.Load() is actually an IEnumerable interface, so basically foreach will iterate through IEnumerable and then add a new Service associated with the ID?

Comment: Regarding your updated question, please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to instantiate your list, you need:

```
private Dictionary<string, Service> serviceList = new Dictionary<string, Service>();
   private void GetList(string ID){
    ....
```

To answer your initial question: Yes, a new instance is created for each item in the collection being iterated over.

Answer (score 1):

you  are just declaring the dictionary you  need to initialize  it

do this

```
private Dictionary<string, Service> serviceList = new  Dictionary<string, Service>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That exactly you do. When you call `new Service ()` you create a new instance of the class, except if Service is a singleton class

Comment: Normally you can't invoke constructors on singletons, so that case would probably not work/compile anyways!